# Caputure correct part of string based on it's relationship

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, response-headers

I am receiving the following response header from an API request *(as String)*:

```
<https://example1>; rel="previous", <https://example2>; rel="next"
```

I need to capture the url that relates only to the "next" rel attribute.
I know I can dig that url out of the string as is but I cannot guarantee they will be returned in the order prev, next.

**What is a good way to ensure I capture the correct url that is associated with the next param?**

I would prefer to know how to do this in vb but am happy to translate a C# answer.

Comment: What is the actual response? There are no such HTTP response headers. In HTML the [link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) is used to refer to external resources including CSS with `rel="stylesheet"`. It's also possible to [specify next/previous pages](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev) in a paged result set, but as the linked Google Search page shows, this is no longer affects indexing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it's a "link" header response that is returned as a string. Don't tell me there's an easy way to strip out a url like that? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example shows me that the "parts" of previous and next are separated by a comma, so we can split the string into two at the comma, find which one contains `rel="next"`, then substring inside it to get the URL, something like

```cs
const string response = "<https://example1>; rel=\"previous\", <https://example2>; rel=\"next\"";
var split = response.Split(',');

var url = string.Empty;
foreach (var part in split)
{
    var trimmed = part.Trim();
    if (!trimmed.Contains("rel=\"next\""))
        continue;

    url = trimmed.Substring(0, trimmed.IndexOf(';'));
    url = url.TrimStart('<');
    url = url.TrimEnd('>');
}

Console.WriteLine(url);
```

Check out [the demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tdMTYs)

Comment: Is that the actual string? There are no such response headers. There are HTML `link` elements. An HTML parser can easily detect link elements far more safely than trying eg to strip HTML elements then try to search into inner text

Comment: Yes. A regular expression could handle the *exact* string you posted. HTML can't be parsed easily with regular expressions or string splitting.  HTML parser libraries like [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) can parse the entire document and allow you to either explore elements or find specific elements using LINQ or CSS selector queries. You could ask specifically for `link` elements whose `rel` element is `next`. A `link` is represented as an `IHtmlLinkElement` already

Answer (score 1):

The question's string looks like an HTML link element without the tags. Extracting information from HTML with simple string manipulations or even regular expressions is very fragile because the elements can vary a *lot*. The same element may be empty or have no content and the browser will treat it the same. There may be newlines or extra whitespace between attributes or attribute names and their values.

It seems the actual problem is how to find the URLs of the [next and previous read the next and previous pages in paged results](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev). This used to be done using `link rel='next'` and `link rel='previous'` before Google decided to stop using these as an indication that pages are related. Google's page that explains how `rel` is used for paging doesn't have these links.

It's a lot safer *and* faster to use an HTML parser like [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). The following code retrieves the Google page and searches for the HREF of a `link pre='search'` element. AngleSharp allows searching for elements using DOM/CSS selectors or LINQ. In this case the code is searching using a CSS selector : `link[pre='search']`

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;
using AngleSharp.Html.Dom;

IBrowsingContext context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader());
var url="https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev";
IDocument document = await context.OpenAsync(url);

var link = document.QuerySelector<IHtmlLinkElement>("link[rel='search']");
Console.WriteLine(link.Href);
```